# How to generate serialVersionUID programmatically in Java?

Tags: java, serialization, serialversionuid

I am working on a project that generates **Java** files.  I'd like to be able to optionally add  the `serialVersionUID` as you would with the [serialver](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/serialver.html) tool.

Is there a way to do this when I generate the **Java** code, or will I need to ask the user of the tool to provide UIDs manually?  To be clear, I'm not looking to do this automatically through Eclipse or the `serialver` tool, but to do it via **Java** itself.

Comment: Maybe the hashcode of the class name of the class being generated would work?

Comment: I was thinking about something like that, wondering if there is a way to do it that is equivalent to the serialver tool though, if possible.

Comment: Sure, you can do it like the serialver tool does it. Just find the logic behind its `serialVersionUID` generation. I've been looking with no success so far.

Comment: Found what you were looking for @bn. Check my answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a version of the `serialver` tool source available [from OpenJDK](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/tools/serialver/SerialVer.java). It all comes down to this call:

```
ObjectStreamClass c = ObjectStreamClass.lookup(MyClass.class);
long serialID = c.getSerialVersionUID();
System.out.println(serialID);
```

In JDK 6 at least it returns the same number with `serialver` tool.

Comment: I tried this and the result was that it didn't detect new changes made in the class when deserializing from an old version. It seems that you always get a 0 from method getSerialVersionUID(), so the serial ID never changes along with the class. It seems to me that you can't set that ID programatically.

Answer (score 5):

From [`ObjectStreamClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectStreamClass.html%E2%80%8E):

```
/**
 * Computes the default serial version UID value for the given class.
 */
private static long computeDefaultSUID(Class<?> cl) {
    if (!Serializable.class.isAssignableFrom(cl) || Proxy.isProxyClass(cl))
    {
        return 0L;
    }

    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(bout);

        dout.writeUTF(cl.getName());

        int classMods = cl.getModifiers() &
            (Modifier.PUBLIC | Modifier.FINAL |
             Modifier.INTERFACE | Modifier.ABSTRACT);

        /*
         * compensate for javac bug in which ABSTRACT bit was set for an
         * interface only if the interface declared methods
         */
        Method[] methods = cl.getDeclaredMethods();
        if ((classMods & Modifier.INTERFACE) != 0) {
            classMods = (methods.length > 0) ?
                (classMods | Modifier.ABSTRACT) :
                (classMods & ~Modifier.ABSTRACT);
        }
        dout.writeInt(classMods);

        if (!cl.isArray()) {
            /*
             * compensate for change in 1.2FCS in which
             * Class.getInterfaces() was modified to return Cloneable and
             * Serializable for array classes.
             */
            Class<?>[] interfaces = cl.getInterfaces();
            String[] ifaceNames = new String[interfaces.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < interfaces.length; i++) {
                ifaceNames[i] = interfaces[i].getName();
            }
            Arrays.sort(ifaceNames);
            for (int i = 0; i < ifaceNames.length; i++) {
                dout.writeUTF(ifaceNames[i]);
            }
        }

        Field[] fields = cl.getDeclaredFields();
        MemberSignature[] fieldSigs = new MemberSignature[fields.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            fieldSigs[i] = new MemberSignature(fields[i]);
        }
        Arrays.sort(fieldSigs, new Comparator<MemberSignature>() {
            public int compare(MemberSignature ms1, MemberSignature ms2) {
                return ms1.name.compareTo(ms2.name);
            }
        });
        for (int i = 0; i < fieldSigs.length; i++) {
            MemberSignature sig = fieldSigs[i];
            int mods = sig.member.getModifiers() &
                (Modifier.PUBLIC | Modifier.PRIVATE | Modifier.PROTECTED |
                 Modifier.STATIC | Modifier.FINAL | Modifier.VOLATILE |
                 Modifier.TRANSIENT);
            if (((mods & Modifier.PRIVATE) == 0) ||
                ((mods & (Modifier.STATIC | Modifier.TRANSIENT)) == 0))
            {
                dout.writeUTF(sig.name);
                dout.writeInt(mods);
                dout.writeUTF(sig.signature);
            }
        }

        if (hasStaticInitializer(cl)) {
            dout.writeUTF("<clinit>");
            dout.writeInt(Modifier.STATIC);
            dout.writeUTF("()V");
        }

        Constructor[] cons = cl.getDeclaredConstructors();
        MemberSignature[] consSigs = new MemberSignature[cons.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < cons.length; i++) {
            consSigs[i] = new MemberSignature(cons[i]);
        }
        Arrays.sort(consSigs, new Comparator<MemberSignature>() {
            public int compare(MemberSignature ms1, MemberSignature ms2) {
                return ms1.signature.compareTo(ms2.signature);
            }
        });
        for (int i = 0; i < consSigs.length; i++) {
            MemberSignature sig = consSigs[i];
            int mods = sig.member.getModifiers() &
                (Modifier.PUBLIC | Modifier.PRIVATE | Modifier.PROTECTED |
                 Modifier.STATIC | Modifier.FINAL |
                 Modifier.SYNCHRONIZED | Modifier.NATIVE |
                 Modifier.ABSTRACT | Modifier.STRICT);
            if ((mods & Modifier.PRIVATE) == 0) {
                dout.writeUTF("<init>");
                dout.writeInt(mods);
                dout.writeUTF(sig.signature.replace('/', '.'));
            }
        }

        MemberSignature[] methSigs = new MemberSignature[methods.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
            methSigs[i] = new MemberSignature(methods[i]);
        }
        Arrays.sort(methSigs, new Comparator<MemberSignature>() {
            public int compare(MemberSignature ms1, MemberSignature ms2) {
                int comp = ms1.name.compareTo(ms2.name);
                if (comp == 0) {
                    comp = ms1.signature.compareTo(ms2.signature);
                }
                return comp;
            }
        });
        for (int i = 0; i < methSigs.length; i++) {
            MemberSignature sig = methSigs[i];
            int mods = sig.member.getModifiers() &
                (Modifier.PUBLIC | Modifier.PRIVATE | Modifier.PROTECTED |
                 Modifier.STATIC | Modifier.FINAL |
                 Modifier.SYNCHRONIZED | Modifier.NATIVE |
                 Modifier.ABSTRACT | Modifier.STRICT);
            if ((mods & Modifier.PRIVATE) == 0) {
                dout.writeUTF(sig.name);
                dout.writeInt(mods);
                dout.writeUTF(sig.signature.replace('/', '.'));
            }
        }

        dout.flush();

        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        byte[] hashBytes = md.digest(bout.toByteArray());
        long hash = 0;
        for (int i = Math.min(hashBytes.length, 8) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            hash = (hash << 8) | (hashBytes[i] & 0xFF);
        }
        return hash;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new InternalError();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        throw new SecurityException(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jeffrey... Quite Crafty +1

Comment: Doesn't look like a copy-pasteable code. Where is the hasStaticInitializer() method declared? Where is the MemberSignature class declared?

Answer (score 4):

If your tool is generating brand new code you don't have any need to compute it the way `serialver` does. Just use 1, or -1, or whatever you like.

Comment: Could you explain why?  Is this because it is a new class?

Comment: @bn. As it's a new class, there are no existing serializations of it, so there is nothing to be compatible to.

Answer (score 3):

Try the hashcode of the class name of the class being generated.

There could be collisions as a hashcode is not unique, but those collisions are statistically unlikely.

[Here's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/class.html#4100) on how serialVersionUID values are generated. Its much more complex than I'd have guessed.

Because of its complexity, I'd either have the user type in the UID themselves, or just use a simple hash of the full classname.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old thread but, I guess, **serialVersionUID** is still one of the hot topics.

When I started to write Java codes, it was too hard to find and assign a unique value to **serlialVersionUID** variable for me. After a while, simple date time format (yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss) gave me the idea: *Why don't I generate a value from current date and time?*

So, I started to generate (of course manually) values according to current date and time.

Let's say current date and time is 01/09/2015 11:00pm. I would assign 201601091100L value to serialVersionUID.

I hope this idea helps you for further improvements in your projects.

Comment: By the way, that format for date-time strings is defined by the very useful [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. The hyphens and colons are optional as you have shown, called the "basic" variation. The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later uses ISO 8601 formats by default in parsing/generating string representations of date-time values.

Comment: You don't need to assign a unique number. You can use 1 or -1.